# Apache .htaccess rewrite php to js and execute js file as php script

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the folowing rewrite rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule     ^js_([A-Za-z0-9\.\_\-]{1,50})\.php$  libjs/misc/$1.js
```

so js_messages.php url links to libjs/misc/messages.js file

It's working good, but now i need to execute php code from some .js files.

How can i do that?
Thanks.

P.S. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your server setup and what the hosting provider lets you do I would use SetHandler to tell apache to send .js files to the php module:

Something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$|\.js$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Can you edit the configuration file for Apache? is this a shared webhosting? can you overwrite any setting from .htaccess ?

Comment: Thank you! This is right answer, but it works only for php as an apache module, i have php as a fastcgi configuration and my solution is little different